# get sequence of div from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 9 HTML divs as:

```
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>


<div id="9">9</div>
```

**Now sequence in HTML is : (id) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**

These divs can be rearranged to get any order in the DOM.

Say after swapping the DOM is like this:

```
<div id="8">8</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="5">5</div>


<div id="1">1</div>
```

**(after swapping/reordering) Now sequence in HTML is : (id) 8 2 5 3 4 7 9 6 1**

I want to get the **order(8 2 5 3 4 7 9 6 1)** of div in a span.

```
<div id="show">Now the sequence is <span id="seq"> </span></div>
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: read all div html content add it in text and set it in seq innerhtml ..whats issue here?

Comment: My bad skills of javascript :(

Comment: please show code that u have tried @b0y

Comment: Start writing js and if you stuck ask us and provide what you have done yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common class to get all the div that you need. Then use `each` to get it's text(or id) and form a string and append it to the dom

**HTML**

```
<div id="8" class="sqDiv">8</div>
<div id="2" class="sqDiv">2</div>
<div id="5" class="sqDiv">5</div>
<div id="1" class="sqDiv">1</div>
<span id="sqDom"></span>
```

JS

```
var _sq="";
var getDivs = $(".sqDiv");
getDivs.each(function(item,index){

 _sq+=$(this).text().trim()+' ';
})
$("#sqDom").text(_sq);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k5v6gfgg/2/)

Comment: I used .data('customAttr') to catch the value of my custom attribute, and it worked fine :) 
Thanks User!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** method and do something like

```js
$('#seq').text(
  $('#parent div') // get the swapped divs
  .map(function() { // iterate over them to generate an array
    return this.id // return id for array element
  }).get() // get result as an array
  .join(' ') // join the array element 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="8">8</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="5">5</div>
  <div id="1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="show">Now the sequence is <span id="seq"> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$("ul div").each(function(){
   $("#seq").text($("#seq").text() + $(this).attr("id") + " ");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c1huL0jL/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this https://plnkr.co/edit/FxemUZMAmEqo2oXvvMXN?p=preview

**JS**

```
var IDs2 = [];
$("#swapping").find("div").each(function(){ IDs2.push(this.id); });
$("#seq2").html(IDs2)
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="swapping"> 
<div id="8">8</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="show2">Now the sequence is <span id="seq2"> </span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that using $.each loop,

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="8">8</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="show">Now the sequence is <span id="seq"> </span></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var divs=[];var seq=[];
divs=$("div");
$.each(divs,function(k,v){
if($(v).attr('id')!='show')
{
seq[k]=$(v).attr('id');
}
})
$('#seq').text(seq);
```

[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/oz5sk6hs/)